# What does “fall for a bluff” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, contemporary-english

New York Times (August 6) reported under the title, “[25 years after Gardner Museum heist, video raises questions](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/07/arts/design/25-years-after-gardner-museum-heist-video-raises-questions.html)” that Federal officials released a video tape recording a guardsman, Richard Abath’s actions on his duty at the Isabella Stewart Gardner Museum in the morning of March 18, 1990, the day 13 artworks including three Rembrandts and a Vermeer were stolen from the Museum. It reads:

> In 1990, Richard Abath, a 23-year-old who, while moonlighting as a security guard, allowed two thieves posing as police officers to enter the Isabella Stewart Gardner Museum here. For 25 years, his decision to buzz in the men who carted away $500 million worth of art has been largely treated as the hapless act of a rookie watchman who **fell for a bluff**.

I can understand “fall from a bluff,” but I don’t know what “fall for a bluff” means. By Googling, I barely found “fell for a  bluff” in the [Sport Rack's article](http://www.sportrack.co.za/interviews/2015/03/15/stormers-captain-says-they-fell-for-chiefs-bluff/) (March 15, 2015):

> “The Stormers finally surrendered their unbeaten record when they were defeated 28-19 by the visiting New Zealand side, the Chiefs, in the Super Rugby match at Newlands on Saturday afternoon. After the match, Stormers captain Duane Vermeulen said his side **fell for a Chiefs bluff**.”

I don’t find “fall for a bluff” as an idiom in English dictionaries at hand, nor its currency on Google Ngram. What does it mean? Is this a popular English idiom?

Comment: Look up *fall for* and *bluff* separately.

Comment: Have voted to close. The OP can find the answer to this question by looking up *fall for* and *bluff* in a dictionary.

Comment: @Araucaria. True. I should have checked the meaning of "fall for." I took "fall for a bluff" altogether for an idiom. It's jump the gun. ChipherBot and Elliot Frisch, thanks a lot for your kind answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluff definition from Google:

> An attempt to deceive someone into believing that one can or is going
>   to do something.

So basically it is saying that a rookie watchman fell for a bluff (fell for an attempt to deceive him).

Answer (score 3):

It's a reference to the card game poker. To [bluff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluff_%28poker%29) (from Wikipedia) is to

> In the card game of poker, a *bluff* is a bet or raise made with a hand which is not thought to be the best hand. To *bluff* is to make such a bet.

To fall for a *bluff* is to fall for a deceitful proposition.